# Fire SQL Trigger When Column Value Changes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am adding the date to a column in SQL when the 'workstatus' is 'completed', but my problem is, when I open and save the same job again in the software, it runs the trigger and changes the date again to a new value which I don't want.

I want the trigger to run only if the 'workstatus' value is something else than 'completed'.

```
    GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TRJCD_JOBREQUEST]    Script Date: 06/25/2021 15:49:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER            TRIGGER [dbo].[TRJCD_JOBREQUEST] ON [dbo].[TBL_JOBREQUEST] 
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT

AS

if (Update (workstatus))

begin

DECLARE @Jobcompletiondate datetime 
DECLARE @workstatus VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @jobid int


select @workstatus = workstatus from inserted
select @jobid = jobid from inserted
select @Jobcompletiondate = GETDATE() 

begin

if @workstatus='Completed'


    update TBL_JOBREQUEST set JobCompDate=@Jobcompletiondate where jobid = @jobid 
end
end
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Your trigger has an [all too common issue](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: The trigger runs when the specified statement(s) are executed, not when you _want_ it to run. You can use `deleted` and `inserted` to determine the _before_ and _after_ values of specific columns and decide what to do within the trigger. Note that the [`update()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns `true` whether or not the value of the column was altered, e.g. `update Foo set Bar = 42 where Bar = 42;` will cause `Update( Bar )` to be `true`.

Comment: IF UPDATE() does not do what you think. And if it is running for rows where there is no actual change in workstatus column, then you have a flawed application that is updating rows in a manner that is inefficient. Fix both. You need to compare the old and new values if your code must ONLY run when the column changes.

Comment: thanks @HABO. i am not sql expert. can you please edit the code for me to compare old new value? i want to update date in the 'JobCompDate' column only when 'workstatus' has existing value as 'pending' and new value is 'completed'. i tried this statement but it dint work ***[update TBL_JOBREQUEST set JobCompDate=(at)Jobcompletiondate where jobid = (at)jobid and workstatus<>'Completed']***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I do not have your data set, so I'm unable to test the trigger, however, based on what you provided in your question, I believe this is the answer you are seeking:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER            TRIGGER [dbo].[TRJCD_JOBREQUEST] ON [dbo].[TBL_JOBREQUEST] 
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT

AS

if (Update (workstatus))

begin

DECLARE @Jobcompletiondate datetime 
DECLARE @currentworkstatus VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @oldworkstatus VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @jobid int


select @oldworkstatus = workstatus from deleted
select @currentworkstatus = workstatus from inserted
select @jobid = jobid from inserted
select @Jobcompletiondate = GETDATE() 

begin

if @currentworkstatus='Completed' and @oldworkstatus <> 'Completed'


    update TBL_JOBREQUEST set JobCompDate=@Jobcompletiondate where jobid = @jobid 
end
end
```

You needed to check if the deleted `workstatus` does not equal `Completed` and only then should the trigger fire.

Comment: Which row will this process when a single `insert` or `update` statement affects more than one row, i.e. `inserted` and `deleted` contain multiple rows?

Comment: it is only updating one row based on the job id. the software is inserting all data into columns in one row only.

Comment: How does `select @jobid = jobid from inserted` get the correct one value from 10 rows in `inserted`?

Comment: store procedures on this table only insert 1 job id and it is updating/inserting only 1 row in the table.

Comment: @MohammadFerozKhan You should add a check for your reality, e.g. `if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 begin rollback transaction; throw 50666, N'TRJCD_JOBREQUEST: No more than one row may be processed because it takes a little more effort.', 42; end;`, to the trigger. Whether it's a change to an SP or a user running an ad-hoc query you should detect the issue and deal with it rather than failing silently. Or fix the code so it works for multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how you should construct your trigger.

There is no need to assign any values to variables, triggers fire once per *batch* and always operate on the *set* of updated rows.

If you update a status to Completed you need to check it's not currently Completed, also if you want to retain the first JobCompDate even if the status is amended afterwards simply use a `case` expression to only update the column where it's currently NULL.

```
create or alter trigger [dbo].[TRJCD_JOBREQUEST] on [dbo].[TBL_JOBREQUEST] 
after update,insert
as
if @@RowCount=0 return

set nocount on
if Update (workstatus)
begin

    update t set
        t.JobCompDate=case when t.JobCompDate is null then GetDate() else t.JobCompDate end
    from inserted i join TBL_JOBREQUEST t on t.jobid=i.jobid
    where i.workstatus='Completed' 
    and not exists (
      select * from deleted d 
      where d.jobid=i.jobid and d.workstatus=i.workstatus
    )

end
```

Comment: How does this work for an `insert` statement that leaves `deleted` empty? An otter _[sic]_ join might be helpful.

Comment: @HABO Yes indeed thank you for pointing that out - with it being both and insert & update it should not have been an inner join on deleted - I have amended to use `exists`

Comment: Why have you chosen to update rows without changing the value of `JobCompDate` (by using a `case` expression) rather than including the `t.JobCompDate is NULL` condition in the `where` clause? Does it improve performance? Aside: The OP, following the standard rules for DDL concealment, hasn't hinted that the column is nullable.